# Excel VBA page break issue using FitToPageWide

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to add pageBreaks on some specified rows while printing and they are all working perfectly with `.PageSetup.Zoom` set to some number but if i use `.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1`  and set `.PageSetup.Zoom` to false they are being completely ignored

here a small chunk of my code im using for this

```
    With ActiveSheet

        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$V$150"
        .PageSetup.Zoom = False
        .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
        .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Cells(50, 1)
        .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Cells(101, 1)
```

If i comment out FitToPagesWide and set Zoom to some random value the pagebreak works perfectly

Comment: If you add `.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False`, does that work? (after `FitToPagesWide = 1`)

Comment: yes it does thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$V$150"
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
End With

ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone   ' remove all existing pagebreaks

With ActiveSheet
    .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Cells(50, 1)
    .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Cells(101, 1)
End With
```

The concept behind is to control the order of changes. This way you can force Excel to recalculate pagebreaks and then you can set the new pagebreaks.